# How to invite another user in firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

we are working for an app with firebase analytics we want to have another user to access the analytics because currently the only one that can access it is the account that you registered firebase with. Is there a way to add or invite another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto "users and permissions" then add a member and assign a Analytics admin role:

[image]